# Optimise Entity Framework query with large record set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I need to optimise the following EF query as initially I am bringing back everything back from the CustomerWidgets table.     Now the table has 100,000 rows it is starting to become slow.   I am querying a sql server dbase.

I guess I don’t need to bring everything back first so what is the best approach to modify the code below?

```
        public List<CustomerWidget> SearchWidgets(string surname, string firstname, string ZipCode)
    {
        // i don't need to bring back everything here!!  optimize it I say!!
        var widgetSearchResults = _context.CustomerWidgets.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(surname))
        {
            widgetSearchResults =
                widgetSearchResults.Where(x => x.Surname.ToUpper().Contains(surname.ToUpper())).ToList();
        }


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
        {
            widgetSearchResults =
                widgetSearchResults.Where(x => x.Forename.ToUpper().Contains(firstname.ToUpper())).ToList();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZipCode))
        {
            widgetSearchResults =
                widgetSearchResults.Where(
                    x => x.ZipCode.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper().Contains(ZipCode.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper()))
                    .ToList();
        }

        return widgetSearchResults;
    }
```

Comment: ToList executes your query. In the worst case you're loading data which you filter afterwards. Just call ToList at the end, when your query is logically built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `ToList()` at the end only, and work with `IQueryable` before:

```cs
public List<CustomerWidget> SearchWidgets(string surname, string firstname, string ZipCode)
{
    var widgetSearchResults = _context.CustomerWidgets.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(surname))
    {
        widgetSearchResults =
            widgetSearchResults.Where(x => x.Surname.ToUpper().Contains(surname.ToUpper()));
    }


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
    {
        widgetSearchResults =
            widgetSearchResults.Where(x => x.Forename.ToUpper().Contains(firstname.ToUpper()));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZipCode))
    {
        widgetSearchResults =
            widgetSearchResults.Where(
                x => x.ZipCode.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper().Contains(ZipCode.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper()));
    }

    /********************
      Call ToList() only here
      *******************/

    return widgetSearchResults.ToList();
}
```

EF constructs the whole SQL query when actually retrieving the elements from the database, so with your method, you are first retrieving:

```sql
SELECT * FROM CustomerWidgets WHERE IsDeleted = false
```

And then the rest of your queries are executed from the in-memory list (of 100.000 items).

By removing the `ToList()` calls till the very end, you work with an `IQueryable`, which is just adding `Where` clauses, and gets constructed and retrieved only when you call `ToList()`, so your SQL query ends up being something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM CustomerWidgets WHERE 
           IsDeleted = false 
       AND UPPER(Surname) LIKE UPPER('%Something%')
       AND UPPER(FirstName) LIKE UPPER('%Something%')
       AND UPPER(ZipCode) LIKE UPPER('%Something%') -- plus all the replacing
```

Which should retrieve only the exact items you want to query for

For extra optimization, you might want to remove all those `ToUpper` and set a collation in SQL server which is case insensitive (those with a `CI` in the name): with correct indices, this should be *MUCH* faster than converting your strings to uppercase in the query.

Also, your `ZipCode` replacing (for `" "` to `""`) should preferably get out of the `Where` clause, so you could do:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZipCode))
    {
        ZipCode = ZipCode.Replace(" ", "");
        widgetSearchResults =
            widgetSearchResults.Where(
                x => x.ZipCode.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper().Contains(ZipCode.ToUpper()));
    }
```

This would still call the `REPLACE` SQL function on the column tho (not on the `where` clause). You could just not replace anything there: it would be faster for SQL Server to check for extra empty spaces than to call a function for every row. A warning though: this could change the functionality: with your current code, "01 05" would match "0 105"; without the replacement, "01 05" would **only** match "01 05". If that doesn't work for you, keep the replaces.

*PS: I haven't tested if your queries would convert directly to SQL Server (it may raise an exception if they don't)... at first glance, I think they should convert well, but if they don't, it should be easy to work out those expressions first.*

Other than this, if your application allows it, you could use paging (using `Skip` and `Take` in Linq) if you want to retrieve less elements at once... but I see no further optimizations that you could take.

To recap:

1. Construct the query with the `WHERE` clauses instead of retrieving all and then filter in-memory. This is done by calling `ToList()` at the end
2. Remove all unnecessary per-row functions (specifically `ToUpper` in this case). If you can change the column collation, SQL Server will perform case insensitive searches.
3. No need to replace `" "` with `""` on both the record and the query clause. It'll be faster if you don't. Check the warning on the answer text though.
4. Make the correct indices on SQL Server
5. Use paging if that's not enough and your application supports paging

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply.   So is there a way to stop the initial query to retrieve everything and only query when a value has been passed?  For example 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
then only query

Comment: You could throw an exception or return an empty list if no clauses have been defined

Comment: Yes thank you.   So to return an empty list from EF  List<CustomerWidget>

How would I set this?

Comment: You just return a "new List<CustomerWidget>()". Sorry about the formatting, I'm on my phone